# MVC4 custom layout issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, layout

I have created custom layout in mVC4 which is rendering fine with normal URL like

http://myhost.com:2475/User/CreateUser

but when i add parameter in my url like

http://myhost.com:2475/User/CreateUser/1

the layout gets disturbed and completely fails While debugging it shows the layout property which I set to my custom layout but the layout fails.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'fails'?

Comment: @Peter it doesnot work...

Comment: I mean is any of the content from your layout page being included? Do you see it in there when you view source?

Comment: @Peter yes by viewing page source from browser it displays everything like normal but not the way that it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

The issue causing the disruption in the design layout was MVC routing which is conflicting with the layouts, causing inconsistent design when accessed from several route paths. The issue can be resolved by bundling technique by combining your style sheets and scripting files   in bundles and referencing them in your layout page by @Styles.Render("your style bundle path") and @Scripts.Render("your script bundle path") methods. The bundle(s) can be configured in bundleconfig.cs file located within App_Start folder.
                The bundles resolves the routing issue moreover it reduces the loading time of your css and script files by using minification technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Bundles like suggested by zeeshan above you can use `@Url.Content("~/path/to.css")` to always render the path from the root of your application